# Add Datefield custom field to Event page in Silverstripe

Tags: php, admin, custom-fields, silverstripe, datefield

I have tried for the past few days adding a custom datefield to my event page using the following articles:

http://www.silverstripe.org/data-model-questions/show/14274
http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/trunk/reference/datefield

My final approach was following this code as is: 
http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/tutorials/2-extending-a-basic-site#showing-the-latest-news-on-the-homepage

Here's my code:

```
    <?php
class EventPage extends Page {
    public function getCMSFields() {
        $fields = parent::getCMSFields();

        $dateField = new DateField('Date', 'Article Date (for example: 20/12/2010)');
        $dateField->setConfig('showcalendar', true);
        $dateField->setConfig('dateformat', 'dd/MM/YYYY');

        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', $dateField, 'Content');

        return $fields;
    }
}
class EventPage_Controller extends Page_Controller {
}
```

Problem I'm facing is: 
Trying to build, it doesn't build completely i.e. doesn't build everything and doesn't give me the message that the build is complete now.

Going afterwards to the admin page, I am seeing white blank screen even though I have the enviornment is set to dev and display errors is all in the config file:

```
Director::set_environment_type('dev');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you also set a $db object attribute so the field has somewhere in the database to save?

```
private static $db = array(
    'Date' => 'Date'
);
```

I don't see any obvious errors in your code above, you have taken the correct approach. Did the dev/build work before you added this code? Might be something completely unrelated causing the issue?

Comment: yes I have it in there in the same event page. I see it is something related to this page.. when I remove this code (i.e. everything related to the datefield), everything else works just fine.

Comment: Is there anything in your Page class that could be causing the issue? given that EventPage extends from Page.

Comment: Have you checked your error log? The code you've provided won't be ran during dev/build. The only way it would cause the error is if there was a php parse error (which it doesn't look like there is).

Comment: @micmania1 how would i check the error log? I can't seem to find anything other than a blank screen browser. please advise! thanks!

Comment: That depends what your setup is. Ubuntu is normally /var/log/apache2/error.log. You can try setting ini_set("display_errors", 1) & ini_set("display_startup_errors", 1) in your _ss_environment.php file.